# "Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'" warning when using BGI?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

i'm working c++ graphics on code block for first time and i get the error

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings
```

can anyone help me?

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int gd = 0;
    int gm;

    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
    putpixel(50, 300, 15);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `initgraph` takes a `char*` parameter, and you passed it a string literal, where it decays to a `const char*`. String literals are immutable, and by accessing it through a `char*` it would become possible to try to modify it and invoke UB.

I don't see why it would take a string by non-const pointer unless it intended to modify it, so you probably want to save the literal in an array.

```
char str[] = "blahblah";
initgraph(..., str);
```

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, that's what I meant. I'll clarify it.